# Filling up an array of struct from file

Tags: c

Apparently it is a very simple task, but I have been struggling with it for some time so far.

I am inizializating an array of structs. Each struct is made by two arrays.

I am then trying to read from a file and to fill my array of structs up.
The file, composed by strings, is something like:

```
sign1 path1
sign2 path2
sign3 path3
```

I get my problem in filling up and then in printing my array.
Any help is strongly appreciated.
Thanks!

```
typedef struct { 
    char firma[333];
    char path[100];
}riga;

void riempi_riga(riga* r, FILE* f1) {
    //fscanf(f1, "%s %s\n", r->firma, r->path);
    fgets(r->firma, 33, f1);
    fgets(r->path, 100, f1);
    return;
}

void stampa_riga(riga* r) {
    printf("%s %s\n", r->firma, r->path);
    return;
}

int num_lines(FILE *f1) {
    char c;
    int lines = 0;
    while ((c = fgetc(f1)) != EOF)
        if (c == '\n')
            lines++;

    if (c != '\n')
        lines++;
    rewind(f1);
    return lines;
}

int main() {
    riga* file_firme[1000];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    FILE* f1;

    f1 = fopen("C:\\Users\\blabla\\Desktop\\firmaMD5.txt", "r");
    if (f1 == NULL) {
        printf("non sono riuscito ad aprire il file!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int num_righe = num_lines(f1);
    for (i; i < num_righe; i++)
        riempi_riga(&file_firme[i], f1);

    //riempi_riga(r1, f1);
    //stampa_riga(r1);
    //fflush(f1);

    for (j; j < num_righe; j++) {
            stampa_riga(&file_firme[j]);
    }

    if (fclose(f1) != 0)
        printf("non sono riuscito a chiudere il file\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while ((c = fgetc(f1)) != EOF)` --> `fgetc` returns `int`.  `c` needs to be `int` not `char`

Comment: thanks! but that does not solve my problem. Any further help please?

Comment: "I get my problem in filling up and then in printing my array" what's our exact problem? and BTW having the variable names & text in italian penalizes the clarity of the question.

Comment: Yeah.  I know.  But what problem are you running into?  I don't see anything necessarily wrong with what you have.  Except you might want: `fgets(r->firma, 333, f1);` instead of `fgets(r->firma, 33, f1);`  Or better: `fgets(r->firma, sizeof(r->firmat), f1);`

Comment: How is your input formatted?   Do you need to read in an entire line with `fgets` and then tokenize on spaces with `strtok` ?

Comment: the input I am using is like this: 
1d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427 f:\tmptest\test1.txt
2d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427 f:\tmptest\test2.txt
3d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427 f:\tmptest\test3.txt

the output I get is instead like this:

1d413d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427 f:\tmptest\test3.txt     2d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427 f:\tmptest\test2.txt
3d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427 f:\tmptest\test3.txt   d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427 f:\tmptest\test2.txt
d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427 f:\tmptest\test3.txt       98f00b204e9800998ecf8427 f:\tmptest\test2.txt

Comment: I actually need to store each word read on the input in a single field of my struct (so a whole struct will be a full line of my input txt

Comment: Don't put information in comments.  Edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your input is in lines of `sign path` where "sign" and "path" are separated by a space.  You can read an entire line with `fgets` and then call `strtok` to get the two tokens.  This code is untested.

```
void riempi_riga(riga* r, FILE* f1) 
{
    char *tok;
    char buf[sizeof(r->firma)+sizeof(r->path)];
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), f1) != NULL)
    {
        if ((tok = strtok(buf)) != NULL)
        {
            strncpy(r->firma, tok, sizeof(r->firma));
            r->firma[sizeof(r->firma)-1]=0;
            if ((tok = strtok(NULL)) != NULL)
            {
                strncpy(r->path, tok, sizeof(r->path));
                r->path[sizeof(r->path)-1]=0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: couldn't I simply use fscanf(f1, "%s %s", r->firma, r->path)?
what is the negative side in using it? %s automatically stops when meeting a space, doesn't it?

Comment: `fgets` reads up to the newline.  if you want to use the *scanf* variety of functions, i'd suggest `fgets` plus `sscanf`.  be sure to specify a max number of characters in your %s format string.